# pyqt5でマウスプレスイベントが思うように動作しない

Tags: python, python3, pyqt5

pyqt5でグラフ上をクリックしたときに座標が表示されるGUIは次のように書けます。

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets,QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.plot_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyCanvas):
    def plot_figure(self):
        x=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)
        y=np.sin(x)
        self.axes.plot(x,y,"-")
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y")
        self.axes.set_xlim(0,2*np.pi)     




class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        #canvas = MyCanvas(self)
        canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas(self)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.mousePressEvent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('plot')
        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        print(event.xdata)
        print(event.ydata)
        #print(event.x)
        #print(dir(event))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()

    app.exec_()
```

ここで、マウスプレスイベントの関数をMycanvasクラス内に移動させようとしました。そのように書き直したコードが次です。

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets,QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.plot_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)


    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        #print("l")
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print(event.xdata)
            print(event.ydata)

        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            print("L")


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyCanvas):
    def plot_figure(self):
        x=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)
        y=np.sin(x)
        self.axes.plot(x,y,"-")
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y")
        self.axes.set_xlim(0,2*np.pi)     




class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        #canvas = MyCanvas(self)
        canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('plot')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()

    app.exec_()
```

しかし、この後者のコードではグラフ上をクリックしても何も起こりませんでした。エラーすら吐きませんでした。どこが悪かったのでしょうか。

Comment: 動いていますよ。書き換えた後セーブしていないのでは？ ただし`event`の`.xdata`, `.ydata`は存在しないのでエラーになりますが。

Comment: 後者のコードでは.xdata, .ydataの代わりにどのように直せばグラフ上の座標が表示されるのですか？

Comment: どうも`.xdata`, `.ydata`は`matplotlib`の`event`に定義されているもののようです。現在通知されているのは`Qt`の`QMouseEvent`なので、座標は`x()`, `y()`で取得できますが、`Qt`のウインドウ全体の中の座標なので変換が必要でしょう。`Qt`と`matplotlib`を両方使っていても、`matplotlib`の`event`を受け取れるようにする工夫が必要なのでは？

Comment: その工夫を質問させて頂いたつもりだったのですが、分かりにくくてすみません。もう少し考えてみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この記事 [Connect mouse events in a Qt4 application embedding matplotlib canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47238239/9014308) によると、`matloptlib`の[mpl_connect()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.mpl_connect)というメソッドで連携を図るようです。

対応するイベント内容はこちら。[MouseEvent](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent) / [LocationEvent](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.LocationEvent) / [Event](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.Event)

`def mousePressEvent(self,event):`は削除して、代わりに以下を`self.setParent(parent)`の下に入れてください。

```
        self.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press)

    def on_button_press(self,event):
        if event.button == 1: # MouseButton.LEFT:
            print('Left Button')
            print('xdata = ' + str(event.xdata))
            print('ydata = ' + str(event.ydata))
        elif event.button == 3: # MouseButton.RIGHT:
            print('Right Button')
```

---

それから、その先にやりたくなるかもしれない記事がいくつかあります。

[python/matplotlibの図上にてクリックで座標値を取得したりキーボード入力値を取得したりする](https://qiita.com/HajimeKawahara/items/abc24fa2216009523656)

[cross hairs in python animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19935445/9014308) / [matplotlib crosshair cursor in PyQt dialog does not show up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36350771/9014308)

[早く知っておきたかったmatplotlibの基礎知識、あるいは見た目の調整が捗るArtistの話](https://qiita.com/skotaro/items/08dc0b8c5704c94eafb9)

Comment: お手数をかけてしまって申し訳ありませんでした。無事動作しました。さらにプラスアルファの情報を教えて頂き感激です。